Django Template Table custom cells?
I am playing around with django a bit and wanted to create a table which I'm filling with some whatever. I am very new to programming with django and html. I have 4 for loops (sounds like a lot)
{% for row in rows %} 
<tr>
    {% for column in columns %}
           
           {% for item1 in items1 %}
               {% if item1.attribute == column.attribute and something %} 
                      <td>{{item1.name}}</td>
               {% endif %}
           {% endfor %}
                        
           {% for item2 in items2 %}
               {% if something %}
                   <td>{{item2.name}}</td>
               {% endif %}
           {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
 </tr>
{% endfor %}

So as you can see, only if one of the if conditions is true a cell is created. This is obviously not what I want and I know by doing
<td>
{% for column in columns %}
<td>
   {% for item1 in items1 %}
.
.
.
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</td>

there would be a cell for every row and column tuple. However I want to individualy add a different background to each of the item types (item.type exists) like <td bgcolor= "color_name | hex_number | rgb_number"> </td>. I first tried a variable {% with emptycell="yes" %} that I change through a custom filter (which doesn't work anyways) but also as I have heard I shouldn't change variables in my html file. So does anyone maybe have an idea?

You need empty cells in a table, not missing <td>...</td>, so
<td>{% if item1.attribute == column.attribute and something %} 
        {{item1.name}}
    {% endif %} 
</td>

You can also supply some default or alternative contents for the cell with a {% else %} clause.
I'm not sure about the inner loops. In general it would be better to create the table data as a list-of-lists in Python, and pass that to the template as context. Say it's called data, and say you have put "" in the empty cells. Then your template is far more natural courtesy of the programming having been done in a proper programming language (Python). Note that the Django template language is "opinionated" and is deliberately not a full programming environment. The architects of Django were of the opinion that programming should be done in Python, presentation in the template.
<table>
{% for row in data %}

   {% if forloop.first %}
       <tr><th> col_1_header ...</th> ... </tr>
   {% endif %}

   <tr>
   {% for item in row %}
       <td>{{item}}</td>
   {% endfor %}
   </tr>

{% endfor %}
</table>

